# How to run a JUnit test in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, junit

I'm using eclipse and I have downloaded a JUnit test, and imported it into my package that I'm currently working on.
However instead of showing test.java it shows test.java.txt. And when I click 'Run as', JUnit test does not come up as one of the options.

Thank you in advance for your help.!

Comment: Have you tried to rename it to test.java?

Comment: oh thanks, yeah that works. But now when i run it it says no junit test found.

Answer (score 0):

For the "Run as JUnit" option to appear, the file must be a Java file (extension `.java`).

JUnit scans your class for test methods. Depending on the version of JUnit that you're using, it can be done in multiple ways. JUnit before version 4.0 requires your test methods' names to start with the word `test`; with JUnit 4.0 onwards, you can use annotations to designate your test methods.

If your code contains JUnit annotations (such as `@Test`), but JUnit still complains that it can't find any test methods, then it means that you're running JUnit 3.x and not JUnit 4.x.